# Boost.Python and CMake Link and Load Errors

Tags: cmake, boost-python

I have a `main.cpp` like so:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

const char* greeting()
{
    return "Hello world?";
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(test)
{
    using namespace boost::python;

    def("greeting", greeting);
}
```

And a `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
project(test)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

# get boost
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS
                system
                thread
                python
             REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# get python
find_package(PythonLibs REQUIRED)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})

add_library(test SHARED
        main.cpp
    )
```

I can run `cmake` and `make` just fine.  It outputs a nice little `libtest.so` file for me.  To test it out, I have a Python script like so:

```
import libtest

print(libtest.greeting())
```

Running this in the same directory as `libtest.so` gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import libtest
ImportError: /home/travis/projects/boost-python-test/build/libtest.so: undefined symbol: _ZNK5boost6python7objects21py_function_impl_base9max_arityEv
```

Yikes!  The problem is pretty clear with `make VERBOSE=1`...the line creating my `libtest.so` looks like this:

```
/usr/bin/c++  -fPIC   -shared -Wl,-soname,libtest.so -o libtest.so CMakeFiles/test.dir/main.cpp.o -L/usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
```

I'm having a mental block as to why I do not see an `-L/usr/lib/libboost_python-mt-py27.a` on that line.  It clearly worked for `find_package(PythonLibs ...)`.  I'm falling short due to some CMake newbishness.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution to this is quite simple.  One has to explicitly link the libraries with `target_link_libraries` *after* the `add_library` statement.

```
target_link_libraries(test
        ${Boost_LIBRARIES}
        ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES}
    )
```

I'm still not sure why it worked for Python without that.  Magic?

Comment: thanks for posting the answer after you found it yourself, which solved my problem.